# How to Ensure Cards Stay The Same Height/Width

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I have this code, where I have 3 CSS cards in a row with bootstrap.

```html
        <div class="container mt-4">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="reward12"><h1 class="rewardtext12">#50</h1></div>
                            <h5 class="card-title">Hiya how is your day been this is extra long text ?</h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                           <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-info" disabled="disabled">Status - Claimed</button></center>
                            Tag: <span class="tag tag-teal">CSS/HTML</span>
                            <div class="user">
                                <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l7-0J1G0Ue0mcZMw-99kMeVuBmRxiPjyvIYONg=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="user" />
                                <div class="user-info">
                                  <h5>Joey Jenkins</h5>
                                  <small><strong>30s ago</strong></small>
                                </div>
                              </div>
                        
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="reward12"><h1 class="rewardtext12">#50</h1></div>

                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled="disabled">Status - Completed</button></center>
                            Tag: <span class="tag tag-teal">CSS/HTML</span>
                            <div class="user">
                                <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l7-0J1G0Ue0mcZMw-99kMeVuBmRxiPjyvIYONg=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="user" />
                                <div class="user-info">
                                  <h5>Joey Jenkins</h5>
                                  <small><strong>30s ago</strong></small>
                                </div>
                              </div>

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-auto mb-3">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <div class="reward12"><h1 class="rewardtext12">#50</h1></div>

                            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                            <h6 class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted">Card subtitle</h6>
                            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
                            <center><button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Claim</button></center>
                            Tag: <span class="tag tag-teal">CSS/HTML</span>
                            <div class="user">
                                <img src="https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AGF-l7-0J1G0Ue0mcZMw-99kMeVuBmRxiPjyvIYONg=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo" alt="user" />
                                <div class="user-info">
                                  <h5>Joey Jenkins</h5>
                                  <small><strong>30s ago</strong></small>
                                </div>
                              </div>


                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
            <h3>Hi</h3>
<br>
        </div>

<style>
    .user {
  display: flex;
  margin-top: auto;
}

.user img {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}
.user-info h5 {
  margin: 0;
}
.user-info small {
  color: #545d7a;
}

    .reward12 {
        background: green;
        font-weight: bold;
text-align: center;
font-size: large;
height: 30px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: context-menu;

    }
    .rewardtext12 {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-family: 'PT Sans', serif;
        font-weight: bold;

    }
    .tag {
  background: #cccccc;
  border-radius: 50px;
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.tag-teal {
  background-color: #47bcd4;
}
.tag-purple {
  background-color: #5e76bf;
}
.tag-pink {
  background-color: #cd5b9f;
}
</style>
```

This is the result
[image]

As you can see, the first card's height is more because of the longer text length. Is there a way to ensure that the card's height will remain the same even with different size text? (Like turn some of the text into ... if there is too much?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to give the height and width of 100%

```
width:100%;
height:100%;
```

Or if you are using flex then

you can give

```
flex-grow:1; 
height:100%;
```